# LOOPBACK REST API for 'LIKE'

Tags: rest, api, loopback

how can i type the REST API for "LIKE" Query on LoopBack ?

according to Loopback Documentation,
i already try like this :

```
ProductDealers?filter={"where":{"DealerCode":"T001","Active":"true","SKU":{"like":"1000.*"}}}
```

but it nothing happens,
please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like

```
Post.find({
  where: {
    title: {
      like: 'someth.*',
      options: 'i'
    }
  }
});
```

**and for api calls**

```
?filter={"where":{"title":{"like":"someth.*","options":"i"}}}
```

Please take a look at this [**PR**](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/86) for more info

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer , i didn't know why its can't work when i used brackets " {} " 
but when i used " [] " , it works very well, like

```
Products?filter[where][Name][like]=%25" + valFilter + "%25&filter[where][Active]=1&filter[where][Deleted]=0"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but i actually found this after looking for something else.

The problem for most people is, that there is something called **Url Encoding.**

Read more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

So if you stringify your json filter like in the examples above, make sure you put the stringified object into an Uri Encoder which will make sure you will get what you expect and will control the encoding of your values

```js
let t_filter = {
  where: {
    title: {
      like: 'someth.*',
      options: 'i'
    }
  }
};

let result = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(t_filter));
```

After that send the result to your Api and not only the stringified Object